# ¿ Cómo reducir el espacio entre secciones del body?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de reducir el espacio entre secciones del body, los cuales están separadas por las

> frases :
>    **ABOUT US, OUR SERVICES, GET IN TOUCH.**

En la [plantilla original](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Squadfree/) aparece también una flecha debajo que aparece cuando damos en el nav al botón correspondiente, y tiene su animación.No lo  muestro por que no me cabe todo el código.
Osea que la cosa es reducir ese espacio al mínimo, para no perder mucho body.

¿ Habría alguna forma de hacerlo con el código que muestro ?
Esta puesto [tambièn en github](https://github.com/miguelitolaparra/miSitioWeb).
Gracias.

```css
/*creado con la ayuda de Edgar Gutiérrez*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic');
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}

a {
    color: #28c3ab;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #176e61;
}

.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);

}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.navbar-brand h1{
 color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}
#preloader {
    background: #ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}


#loaderInner {
    background:#ffffff url(../img/spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;
    height: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60px;
}

@keyframes boxSpin{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-10px, 0px);
  }
  25%{
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  }
  75%{
    transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
}


@keyframes shadowSpin{
  0%{
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  25%{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px #39CCCC, -10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  50%{
    box-shadow: -10px 10px #39CCCC, 10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  75%{
    box-shadow: -10px -10px #39CCCC, 10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
}

#load {
 z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #FF4136;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -5px auto 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #FF4136;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px #39CCCC, 10px 0px #01FF70;
  animation: shadowSpin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
.marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
.marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}
.home-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}


.section-heading h2 {
 font-size: 40px;
}
.section-heading i {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
 background: #f8f8f8;
}


.bg-dark {
 background: #575757;
}
.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}
.intro {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2q21qq1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}

#intro.intro {
 padding:20% 0 0 0;
}

.intro .slogan {
 text-align: center;

}

.intro .page-scroll {
 text-align: center;
}

.brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.intro .slogan h2 {
 color: #FFF;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-size: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-style: none;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #000;
}

.intro .slogan h4 {
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #000;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}

.boxed-grey {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 padding: 20px;
}

.team h5 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.team p.subtitle {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.avatar {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.team-social {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;

}

.team-social {
 text-align: center;
}

.team-social li{
    display: inline-block;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0;
}


.team-social a{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    display: block;
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3bbec0;
 color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.team-social a i{
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.team-social .social-facebook a{background: #3873ae;}
.team-social .social-twitter a{background: #62c6f8;}
.team-social .social-dribble a{background: #d74980;}
.team-social .social-deviantart a{background: #8da356;}
.team-social .social-google a{background: #000;}
.team-social .social-vimeo a{background: #51a6d3;}
.team-social .social-facebook a:hover{background: #4893ce;}
.team-social .social-twitter a:hover{background: #82e6ff;}
.team-social .social-dribble a:hover{background: #f769a0;}
.team-social .social-deviantart a:hover{background: #adc376;}
.team-social .social-google a:hover{background: #333;}
.team-social .social-vimeo a:hover{background: #71c6f3;}
.service-icon {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form#contact-form .form-group label {
 text-align: left !important;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
form#contact-form input,form#contact-form select,form#contact-form textarea {
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow:  none;
}

form#contact-form input:focus,form#contact-form select:focus,form#contact-form textarea:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}

.validation {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:13px;
}

#sendmessage {
    color: green;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#errormessage {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#sendmessage.show, #errormessage.show, .show {
 display:block;
}

.company-social {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.company-social {
 text-align: left;
}

.company-social li{
    display: inline-block;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0;
}


.company-social a{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    display: block;
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3bbec0;
 color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.company-social a i{
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.company-social .social-facebook a{background: #3873ae;}
.company-social .social-twitter a{background: #62c6f8;}
.company-social .social-dribble a{background: #d74980;}
.company-social .social-deviantart a{background: #8da356;}
.company-social .social-google a{background: #000;}
.company-social .social-vimeo a{background: #51a6d3;}
.company-social .social-facebook a:hover{background: #4893ce;}
.company-social .social-twitter a:hover{background: #82e6ff;}
.company-social .social-dribble a:hover{background: #f769a0;}
.company-social .social-deviantart a:hover{background: #adc376;}
.company-social .social-google a:hover{background: #333;}
.company-social .social-vimeo a:hover{background: #71c6f3;}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 ;

}

footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
}

.credits, .credits a {
    color: #fff;
}

/* ==========================
Parallax
============================= */

#parallax1{
 background-image: url(../img/parallax/1.jpg);
}

#parallax1:after {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: -1;
}


#parallax2{
 background-image: url(../img/parallax/2.jpg);

}

#parallax2:after  {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0.7;
 z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
 border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


.btn-circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
}


.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #999;
    background: #fff;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover i,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus i{
    color: #999;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0 {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0 {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}


#text {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ffcc00;
}

#map {
 height: 500px;
}


.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}


.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28c3ab;
}

.btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}
@media(min-width:767px) {

    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }

    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }


    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }


}
@media (max-width:768px) {

 .team.boxed-grey {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .boxed-grey {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }

 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .tp-banner-container {
  padding-top:40px;
 }

 .page-scroll a.btn-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
 }

}
html .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

html .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <h1>MIGUEL-ESPESO</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#intro">Casa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Formacion</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="intro" class="intro">

    <div class="slogan">
      <h2>Creamos  <span class="text_color"> </span> </h2>
      <h4> la aplicacion que haga crecer su negocio</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about" class="home-section text-center">
    <div class="heading-about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
              <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="container">  
   <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="img/dummy1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />    
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6">  
     <p>Algunas de mis ha</p>   
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%">
      90% - html
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      40% - CSS
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
      50% - Javascript.
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="service" class="home-section text-center bg-gray">
    <div class="heading-about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
              <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
          <hr class="marginbot-50">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
                <img src="img/icons/service-icon-1.png" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>Print</h5>
                <p>Vestibulum tincidunt eni</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
           <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2q21qq1.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>Web Design</h5>
                <p>Vestibu</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2q21qq1.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>Pho</h5>
                <p>Vestibulum  </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <div class="service-box">
              <div class="service-icon">
                <img src="img/icons/service-icon-4.png" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="service-desc">
                <h5>Cloud System</h5>
                <p>Vestibulum tincid</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="contact" class="home-section text-center">
    <div class="heading-contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
              <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
          <hr class="marginbot-50">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="boxed-grey">
            <div id="sendmessage">Thank you!</div>
            <div id="errormessage"></div>
            <form id="contact-form" action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">
                                Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                      <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">
                                Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Message</button>                        
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="widget-contact">
            <h5>Oficina</h5>
 <address><strong>Lugar</strong><br> Olivar, 5<br>    
 La Parra<br><abbr>TLF:</abbr>920
    </address>     
 <address><strong>Email</strong><br></address> 
      <address><ul class="company-social"></ul></address>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El detalle son los padding que se dan entre los divs por ejemplo en tu sección "ABOUT US" aplicas una clase que se llama **home-section** en tu CSS y tienes un `padding-top: 110px;
padding-bottom: 110px;` 
lo cual hace que se separe tanto los divs. 
Ajusta esos valores disminuyendo a `padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;`
y verás el resultado si te gusta o si no pues a jugar con esos valores hasta que queden.

Comment: Gracias compañero @Silvestre Silva, lo solucione reduciendo el `margin-top:20px; margin-botton: 20px; `de la sección : `.section-heading {   }`    que a su vez tenia repetida en otro archivo y se estaba enfrentando.

Answer (score 2):

Casi siempre me sucede que los h1,h2,h3 me dan esos mismos problemas graficos.
Lo que siempre hago es agregar una clase

```
.red {
     background:red !important;
}
```

Para visualizar todo el contenido sea de `div`,`p`o cualquier etiqueta.

Luego de ver correctamente el espacio, en este caso, verifico que los h1,h2,h3 etc.. tengan:

```
h2 {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Si no me gusta como se visualiza, voy modificando el `padding-top` o `padding-bottom` hasta llegar a lo que se quiere lograr.

**EDIT**

Al ver en el *codigo* encontre muchos estilos de margines y paddings. Le recomiendo comprobarlos.

```
  -----------------HTML-----------
  <div class="section-heading">

            <h2>About Us</h2>

            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

    </div>

  -----------------CSS-----------------

 hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
 .marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
 .marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
 .marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
 .marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
 .marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}
 .home-section {
 padding-top: 110px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 z-index:120;
 }
 .section-heading h2 {
font-size: 40px;
 }
 .section-heading i {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Comprueba el estilo dado en esas clases, que no esten generando espacios demás o que no te gusten. *Utilizando lo previamente dicho!*

Comment: Estaba probando lo del compañero, pero lo ha quitado...

Comment: @MiguelEspeso creo que se ha confundido o no ha funcionado. Edite mi respuesta, verifica lo que agregue en **EDIT**

Comment: lo no me funciona tu aportes, se agradece el interés igual.

Comment: Es raro que no funcione ya que los espacios en blanco dados, se estan estableciendo debido a lo mencionado arriba. Además en el código a ejecutar (snippet arriba) , da error en script  y la pagina se visualiza mal. Por ese otro motivo me es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: lo he solucionado con la propuesta del compañero que quito su respuesta, con `.section-heading {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
} `  no me funcionaba porque tenia estilos contraponiendose en otro archivo.

Comment: Exactamente es lo que deciamos previamente. Tenias que verificar los margines y paddings. Lamentablemente como estoy con mucho trabajo te respondi con el lugar del error para que usted lo solucióne.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso he editado mejor mi respuesta. Si has resuelto el problema:  [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ya sé lo que hay que hacer cuando alguien contesta una pregunta @Juan , pero como te digo, lo he solucionado con `.section-heading { margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; } `

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo @Juan